# Displaying elevation profile of vector layer using QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, elevation, profile

I am using QGIS 3.28.

I am trying to generate an elevation profile from a vector layer. I typically use the "Profile Tool" plugin to accomplish this task, but I recently learned that QGIS has released a new tool that does the same thing.

I decided to try out this new tool and was able to generate a profile for a `QgsVectorLayer` using the "capture curve from function" button.

[image]

However, I am having trouble replicating this process using Python. I have looked at the different classes (`QgsElevationProfileCanvas`, `QgsProfilePlotRenderer`, etc.) but am struggling to get the desired results.

I've so far managed to display an image of my profile using the code below.

```py
for feature in newVectorLayer.getFeatures():
        geometry = feature.geometry()
        if geometry.type() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            points = geometry.asPolyline()
            line = QgsLineString(points)
            break

#This part is supposed to create a QImage from LineString and raster
request = QgsProfileRequest(line)
plotrenderer = QgsProfilePlotRenderer([raster], request)

plotrenderer.startGeneration()
plotrenderer.waitForFinished()

image = plotrenderer.renderToImage(7500, 200, 0, 20, -2500, 500, "")
label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
label.show()
```

[image]

However I can't create an interactive dialog box with my profile displayed in it. Here is what I did and I end up with an empty window.

```py
context = QgsRenderContext()
context.setExtent(QgsRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100))
context.setOutputSize(QSize(200, 200))
context.setRenderingStopped(False)

profile = QgsElevationProfileCanvas()
profile.setProfileCurve(line)
profile.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326))
profile.setLayers([raster])

plot2d = Qgs2DPlot()

profile.render(context, 200, 600, plot2d)
profile.show()
```

I am not very familiar with these classes and may have misunderstood the purpose of `QgsRenderContext`, `Qgs2DPlot`, and `QgsElevationProfileCanvas`.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? An image file or an interactive dialog?

Comment: @bugmenot123 Yes I'm trying to get an interactive dialog not only an image